# emacs: adding modes to hide-show alist

Tags: emacs, elisp

I wonder if you know how to get hideshow work with new modes. For instance, I have some extraneous code I want to hide with R. With folding-mode it can simply be

```
(load "folding" 'nomessage 'noerror)
(folding-add-to-marks-list 'ess-mode "# {{{"  "# }}}" nil t)
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'turn-on-folding-mode)
```

I thought the hideshow equivalent would be

```
(add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
         '(ess-mode "# {{{" "# }}}" "#[ #]?"
            hs-forward-sexp 
            hs-c-like-adjust-block-beginning
            ))
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook '(lambda()
                (hs-minor-mode 1)
                (hs-hide-all)
                (custom-set-variables
                 (hs-hide-comments-when-hiding-all 0)
                 )
))
```

but I think there is some magic in hs-forward-sexp that I am not sure how to figure out?

I tried adapting a function written for [c-sharp](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/04/14/making-hideshow-el-work-with-csharp-mode-el-and-region-endregion.aspx) (replacing the regex search on region/endregion with {{{ and }}}) but no luck! I wonder if the solution is obvious to a veteran out there...

Thanks much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify what actually went wrong.  When I tried using your configuration, I found that the `(hs-hide-all)` call failed with the wrong number of arguments because `hs-forward-sexp` takes two arguments, but was being called with one.

Long story short, I can get the hiding to work properly for text mode (with the changes you had above) after fixing your initialization to be:

```
(add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
             '(ess-mode "# {{{" "# }}}" "#[ #]?"
                         forward-sexp 
                         hs-c-like-adjust-block-beginning))
```

You had `hs-forward-sexp` on the 3rd line, but what you really wanted was just regular `forward-sexp`.

*Note:* my testing was actually in `text-mode`, but that shouldn't affect the results.

Comment: I see, did not know about forward-sexp. Thanks Trey!